# MySQL group by multiple columns issue

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

The query below collects temporary overview data for every user into memory table. Basicaly, user sees, count of items by keyword.

The problem is, it calculates total count of items by `keyword_id`.

What I need is, to calculate `item_count` by both `keyword_id` and `item_type` (`Item`.`type`).

```
 SELECT
        `Item`.`user_id` AS `user_id` ,
        `ItemKeyword`.`keywordID` AS `keyword_id` ,
        `Keyword`.`title` AS `keyword_title`,
        count(`ItemKeyword`.`ItemID`) AS `ico_count`
    FROM
        (
            (
                `ItemKeyword`
                JOIN `Item` ON(
                    (
                        `Item`.`id` = `ItemKeyword`.`ItemID`
                    )
                )
            )
            JOIN `Keyword` ON(
                (
                    `Keyword`.`id` = `ItemKeyword`.`keywordID`
                )
            )
        )
    GROUP BY
        `Item`.`user_id` ,
        `ItemKeyword`.`keywordID`;
```

## Details

For example, now result looks like below

[image]

Basicaly, `item_count` is total of all `item_type`s. What I need is, to separate the result below

```
user_id   keyword_id  keyword_title   item_count
1         9645         surveillance    20
```

Into something like this:

```
user_id   keyword_id  keyword_title   item_count item_type
1         9645         surveillance    18           1
1         9645         surveillance    2            2
```

Where, `item_count` are calculated by both `keyword_id` and `item_type`.

I can't figure out how to include `item_type` also into this query.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand your love of brackets (parenthesis). Why so many? in my opinion you lose the readability. It was just a side note.

If you need an extra grouping level you need to modify the query like this:

```
SELECT
    `Item`.`user_id` AS `user_id` ,
    `ItemKeyword`.`keywordID` AS `keyword_id` ,
    `Keyword`.`title` AS `keyword_title`,
    count(`ItemKeyword`.`ItemID`) AS `ico_count`,
    `Item`.`type` AS `item_type` 
FROM `ItemKeyword` JOIN `Item` ON
     `Item`.`id` = `ItemKeyword`.`ItemID`
  JOIN `Keyword` ON
     `Keyword`.`id` = `ItemKeyword`.`keywordID`
GROUP BY
    `Item`.`user_id` ,
    `Item`.`type` ,
    `ItemKeyword`.`keywordID`,
    `Keyword`.`title`;
```

Comment: If its not working you should explain exactly what is not working, error message, results not as expected etc?

Comment: What happens if you run the query without `INSERT INTO`? Try running the query starting with SELECT `Item`.`user_id` AS `user_id` ,

Comment: https://s.mail.ru/22Bj/RH4QWdWZN Look at this result. `item_count` is `10` for both `item_type` `1` and `3`. In fact, `10` is sum of type `1` and type `3`. So what I need is, to seperate total 10 into 2 rows as type 1 - count and type 3 - count. I hope, I explained now:)

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide the sample data. Not as a screenshot please, as a text. Please edit your question with this data and the expected result

Comment: Please see the last part of my question. Updated it

Comment: try now (there was an extra comma in the query that may have affected the result)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138580/discussion-between-demonoid-and-cha).

Comment: No, it's not related to syntax error. The thing that I'm talking about is logical issue

Comment: I insist on sample data. Please provide the data for the user_id 1 with these two types where you do not see the correct count.

Comment: Do not assume that the auto-increment fields in sqlfiddle will start from 1, populate them

Comment: You are explicitly starting your autoincrements from different values. This is obvious simply by printing your input values. Next time make a [mcve]. Learn about debugging. Also foreign keys & relational database integrity.

Comment: cha thanks very much. Please remove sqlfiddle link as it consists of some information about project

Comment: I removed the link